# Why did JUnit declare setUp and tearDown in camelcase, even though each of them is a single word?

Tags: java, coding-standards, junit, camelcase

Reference:

http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html#setUp()

`setUp` should have ideally be named as `setup`

I've explored if any duplicate method `setup` is used in its parent hierarchy, because of which they renamed the method to `setUp`, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

For the moment, there is still a difference between the noun "setup" and the verb "set up":

> Hey Joe, can you *set up* the amp for me?
>
> Dude, that's a sweet stereo *setup* you've got there!

Since procedure names are conceptually verbs, `setUp` is the correct way to spell the method name. I'm aware that this is slowly changing so that both will eventually come to be spelt as one word, but as long as we have the difference, it's a good idea to exploit that difference to increase clarity.

Comment: Likewise, *teardown* is a noun and *tear down* is a verb, so `tearDown` is also correct for a method name.

Comment: "I'm aware that this is slowly changing" I don't agree; the use of single-word "setup", "login", etc as verbs is simply a flagrant grammar error, which manifests immediately when the verb is conjugated: *sets up*, *setting up*, *logged in*. Nobody tries to write "setsup".

Comment: You have a sweet JUnit setup set up! I love your `setUp`, hate to see that get torndown.